# Show() & Hide() 2 WPF windows from Class

Tags: wpf

Hello
WPF Project with 2 windows and a class

```
static class Process
{
    public static Window1 _Window1 = new Window1 ( );
    public static Window2 _Window2 = new Window2 ( );

    public static OpenWindow1 ( )
    {
        if ( _Window2 . ShowInTaskbar )
            _Window2 . Hide ();

        _Window1 . Show ( );
    }

    public static OpenWindow2 ( )
    {
        if ( _Window1 . ShowInTaskbar )
            _Window1 . Hide ();

        _Window2 . Show ( );
    }
}
```

how to do that without threading problems & without using dispatcher ?

Comment: It would be much easier to have a main window that shows and hides itself and the other window.

Comment: i know but i just give an example of 2 windows only
my programs contains about 6 windows so i made as if you can called it a Queen class that manage all windows show , hide & close them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your two statments: I know I must invoke Dispatcher and then later you say you want to do this without using dispatcher. I am going to assume that you simply want to know how to do this without threading problems. If this is not the case please edit your question.

```
public static class Process
{
    public static Window _Window1 = new Window();
    public static Window _Window2 = new Window();

    public static void OpenWindow1()
    {
        if (_Window2.ShowInTaskbar)
        {
            _Window2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(_Window2.Hide);
        }

        _Window1.Show();
    }

    public static void OpenWindow2()
    {
        if (_Window1.ShowInTaskbar)
            _Window1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(_Window2.Hide);

        _Window2.Show();
    }
}
```